# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py'

Tags: python, android, android-ndk, buildozer

I can't compile my project, here is my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vova/.local/bin/buildozer", line 5, in <module>
    from buildozer.scripts.client import main
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 844, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 980, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1037, in get_data
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/vova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py'
```

What Do I have to do to solve this?

Comment: Check the given file and its parent folders for a permission/owner issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how I can do this? I am beginner